# Add/Install java on azure (windows) function with C#?

Tags: azure-functions

Is it possible to add/install java on azure (windows) function with C#?

In Configuration, Application Settings I can set a environment variable and path:
[image]

But then I have to to set the whole jdk's files to "Embedded Resource" & Copy to Output Directory in visual studio (for mac) and it might still not work in the end?

There are extensions that can be installed
:[image]

.. but Java is not there.

Do I need to make a **Java** Azure function instead to have working `JAVA_HOME` dir that apis can work with?

Answer (score 0):

**The best suggestion for you is reading this article first**: [Azure Functions Java developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption#jdk-runtime-availability-and-support)

You should concern that Azure is a **PaaS**, which might cause a lot of limitation operating on environment. So the best way to develop JAVA web app is **creating an app service based on JAVA**, which Azure prepared the environment perfectly.

About using the App Settings, you could set the connection string and runtime stack, etc. Using them like this: `System.getenv("AzureWebJobsStorage")` Refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption#environment-variables).

Comment: I created the azure function in java instead. The problem now is network. It can't open the port I that elastic needs

Comment: It seems it's another kind of question. Would you mind accept my answer and raise another question about the network?